# for loop combine with function to ouput increase value

Tags: r, function, loops

```
l=0
for (j in (1:5)){
  test(j)
}

test<-function(x){
  x
  l=l+0.25
  print(l)
}


I am expecting.
[1] 0.25
[1] 0.50
[1] 0.75
[1] 1.00
[1] 1.25

But, all I got is.
[1] 0.25
[1] 0.25
[1] 0.25
[1] 0.25
[1] 0.25
```

This is simplified version of my code. 
I am trying to make l keeps increasing every time I run the function. 
Can someone give me some advise?
Thank you!

Comment: Your function `test` does not change objects outside of it unless you force it to with `<<-`. But don't do this.

Comment: You are just testing something and not particularly interested in the resulting vector. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your final objective is, but perhaps this will help.

```
test <- function(x) {
  x + 0.25
}

y <- 0
for(i in 1:5) {
  y <- test(y)
  print(y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boxplot(U_percent_all, names=U_name, main=sprintf(("I_Common chr%s vs Tissue \n (unstable)"),i), 
        ylab="GC content", ylim=c(0,1), na.action = TRUE)
abline(h=chr_gc[i,2], col="red")l=0
for (z in (1:5)){
  seg.fun.U(z)
}

seg.fun.U <- function(x){
for ( j in x:ncol(U_percent_all)){
if ((is.na(U_percent_all[,j])==TRUE) || (is.na(U_percent_all[,x])==TRUE)){
  next
}
else if (as.numeric(summary(is.na(U_percent_all[,j]))["FALSE"]<=2)){
  next
}
else if (as.numeric(summary(is.na(U_percent_all[,x]))["FALSE"]<=2)){
  next
}
n<-NULL
n<-t.test(U_percent_all[,x],U_percent_all[,j])$p.value
print(n)
if ((n <= 0.05)==TRUE){
  if ((n <=0.01)==TRUE){
    if ((n <=0.001)==TRUE){
      segments(x0=1, x1=j, y0=0.8+l,y1=0.8+l, col=1)
      text(x=j,y=0.82+l,"***")
      l=l+0.3
    }
    else{
      segments(x0=1, x1=j, y0=0.8+l,y1=0.8+l, col=1)
      text(x=j,y=0.82+l,"**")
      l=l+0.3
    }
  }
  else{
    segments(x0=1, x1=j, y0=0.8+l,y1=0.8+l, col=1)
    text(x=j,y=0.82+l,"*")
    l=l+0.3
  }
 }
}
```

}

Basically, I tried to plot a figure and add significant line on top of each pair. 
In U_percent_all data frame, there are five columns. And, I want to compare significant line of each two pairs. 
In order to avoid longer lines cover shorter one, each line needs to be plotted in one height. That's why I try this way.